# Trim Powershell OutPut

Tags: powershell, trim, character-trimming

Requirement is to trim the Output. Retain only the output quoted within double quotes from Name and remove/avoid the earlier lines/characters

**From:**

```
$R.Output = \\GBVServer1\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="Contoso",Name="Domain Users"

$R.Output = \\GBVServer1\root\cimv2:Win32_SystemAccount.Domain="GBVServer1",Name="INTERACTIVE"
```

**To:**

```
$R.Output = Domain Users

$R.Output = INTERACTIVE
```

Could somebody assist with the powershell switch to be used?

Comment: Check out `trimstart('"')` and `trimend('"')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with regex to capture only the Name part between the quotes for these strings:

```
$regex = [regex]'(?i)Name="([^,]+)"'

$string = '\\GBVServer1\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="Contoso",Name="Domain Users"'
$R.Output = $regex.Match($string).Groups[1].Value  # --> Domain Users

$string = '\\GBVServer1\root\cimv2:Win32_SystemAccount.Domain="GBVServer1",Name="INTERACTIVE"'
$R.Output = $regex.Match($string).Groups[1].Value  # --> INTERACTIVE
```

Regex details:

```
Name="      Match the characters “Name="” literally
(           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [^,]     Match any character that is NOT a “,”
      +     Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
"           Match the character “"” literally
```

<sup>The `(?i)` makes the match case-insensitive</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much :-)